# Unable to read from a tensorflow checkpoint for finetuning

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, nlp

I am trying to use a pre-trained BERT model for fine tuning with SST2 data processor. But when I give the checkpoint of the pre-trained model, it is showing that "Key output_bias not found in checkpoint".

I thought it might be due to errors in the pre-trained BERT model checkpoint. So I did the pre-training again. But, I am still facing the same issue.

```
TASK = 'STS' #@param {type:\"string\"}
TASK_DATA_DIR = 'glue_data/STS-B/'# + TASK

output_dir = 'trained_model/observation'
tf.gfile.MakeDirs(output_dir)

BERT_MODEL = path + 'multi_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12/' 
VOCAB_FILE = os.path.join(BERT_MODEL, 'vocab.txt')   
CONFIG_FILE = os.path.join(BERT_MODEL, 'bert_config.json')   
INIT_CHECKPOINT = os.path.join(BERT_MODEL, 'bert_model.ckpt')   
DO_LOWER_CASE = BERT_MODEL.startswith('cased')

tokenizer = tokenization.FullTokenizer(vocab_file=VOCAB_FILE, 
do_lower_case=DO_LOWER_CASE)

TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE = 1   
EVAL_BATCH_SIZE = 8   
PREDICT_BATCH_SIZE = 8   
LEARNING_RATE = 2e-5   
NUM_TRAIN_EPOCHS = 3.0   
MAX_SEQ_LENGTH = 128   

processors = {   
    "sts": run_classifier.StsProcessor,    
}   

processor = processors[TASK.lower()]()    
label_list = processor.get_labels()
```

The error is:

> NotFoundError: Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely
>   due to a Variable name or other graph key that is missing from the
>   checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected
>   based on the checkpoint.   Original error: Key output_bias not found
>   in checkpoint [[node save/RestoreV2 (defined at
>   /home/subraas3/.conda/envs/tensorflow_13/lib/python3.7/
>   site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py:1403)
>   ]] [[node save/RestoreV2 (defined at
>   /home/subraas3/.conda/envs/tensorflow_13/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py:1403)
>   ]]

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the error message, this error occurs if

1. A layer in the tf compute graph is renamed. i.e the name of the layer in the pre-trained checkpoint is different from what is there in the provided API
2. A new layer is added to API , i.e network architecture is changed. Or,
3. A layer that is present in the pre-trained checkpoint is removed (unlikey).

Please check that the version of the bert API is same as the pretrained checkpoint version. If they are same, you might want to manually check if the tf graph in the checkpoint is consistent with the API, using this [tool.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/inspect_checkpoint.py)